# Adding PHP script to option tag with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have a long select tag with lots of options that I need to add PHP script to them.
I'm trying to make a JQuery script that will help me do it for all the option tags, but have no idea how.
I need jQuery to change this:

```
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
....
<option value="z">Z</option>
```

to:

```
<option value="a" <?= isset($array["a"]) ? "selected" : "" ?>>A</option>
<option value="b" <?= isset($array["b"]) ? "selected" : "" ?>>B</option>
....
<option value="z" <?= isset($array["z"]) ? "selected" : "" ?>>Z</option>
```

How can I achieve this without too much effort? (the list is actually about 200 items long)

I am able to iterate through the list, but I can't seem to add the attributes or whatever.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select option").each(function()
    {
        var attr = " <?=  isset($array['."+$(this).attr("value")+"']) ? 'selected' : '' ?>";
        ///how to add this to the tag??
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making that change with jQuery won't magically execute the stuff in the PHP tags. You have to handle this logic server side.

I suggest writing a PHP script that makes the repetitive changes to the `.php` file in question. Either that, or use an editor with regex support to do it for you.

For example, in Notepad++, you could (regex) replace all occurrences of:

```
(<option value=")([^"]+)(">.+?</option>)
```

with:

```
\1\2<?= isset($array["\2"]) ? "selected" : "" ?>\3
```

Comment: Yes, but adding this code to 200+ lines MANUALLY is quite painful, so I need a "tool" to assist me.

Comment: After the changes are made with jquery I will copy the new option tags to the php page where the server will handle everything else

Comment: @Ilan Yes, those tools are called text editors. They come bundled with IDEs or on their own. How lazy you feel should never be a factor in deciding the logic of your software.

Comment: @Ilan I came up with an example of a regex you could use.

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved me like an hour of tedious copy-past-rename

Answer (score 0):

Though you should separate concerns and you should not be messing PHP with js, just keep it short:

```
$('#select').val('<?php echo $valueYouNeed; ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you just want to generate a php file I would suggest using string/regex replace in your ide/editor

going from

```
<option value="a">A</option>
```

to

```
<option value="a" <?= isset($array["a"]) ? "selected" : "" ?>>A</option>
```

In vim (but other editors should support this too) you can do this with

```
:%s/value=\(".*"\)/value=\1 <?= isset($array[\1]) ? "selected" : "" ?>/g
```

where the part you search for is

```
value=\(".*"\)
```

and this is the part you replace

```
value=\1 <?= isset($array[\1]) ? "selected" : "" ?>
```

using

```
\([someregex]\)
```

you can 'store' some variable and with \1 you can output it in the replace part 1